# Auto Decrement a value in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it's possible to auto decrement a value

Suppose you have this table

```
id |  col1   |
1  | 'test1' | 
2  | 'test2' | 
3  | 'test3' |
```

Then you add another column and start at a value, let's say 30, and decrease the value by one automatically.

```
id |  col1   |  col2 |
1  | 'test1' |  30   |
2  | 'test2' |  29   |
3  | 'test3' |  28   |
```

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `-`?

```
select id, col1, (30 - id) as col2
from t;
```

Perhaps with `row_number()`:

```
select id, col1, (30 - row_number() over (order by id)) as col2
from t;
```

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, 31 - row_number() over(order by id) col2
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you can use a user variable:

```
set @rn = 31;
select t.*, @rn := @rn - 1 col2
from mytable t
order by id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to update col2 based on id though? So we create col2 and it goes through and adds the value 30 to id 1, 29 to id 2, 28 to id 3 without user input? Kind of like what we can do with Auto_Increment